# How to "react" on data changes with RxJS?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

RxJS beginner here: I have problems with saving and tracking data changes using RxJS. Say I structure my app in small views/widgets and every view/widget has its own state and should do things on data changes. How do I do that?

More concrete example. Let's say I have a widget called `Widget` and `Widget` has a title and button. The state should contain the title and the information *if* the button was already clicked. From reading the docs of RxJS it seems this would be a good starting point:

```
var widgetState = new Rx.Subject().startWith({
  wasClicked: false,
  title: 'foo'
});
```

Now I want to be notified if some data changes:

```
var widgetStateChanges = widgetState.subscribe(function(data) {
  console.log('data: ', data);
  // what do i do with the data here?
  // i would like to merge the new data into the old state
});

widgetStateChanges.onNext({ title: 'bar' });
```

I listen to the changes, but I don't know how to *save* them. I would also like to do special things, if a certain data change happens. Something like this.

```
widgetStateChanges.filter(function(e) {
  return e.wasClicked;
}).do(function(e) {
  console.log('Do something because was clicked now.');
});
```

However I can't `filter` a subscription (`widgetStateChanges`), only a subject (`widgetState`).

Comment: Doesn't this run counter to the FRP philosophy? Is there any reason you can't use `.takeLast` inside `.subscribe` to do the merge and then pipe the result to a different stream, which you subscribe/react to?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is really against FRP, it could be. I'm still a newb at this topic. But I thought this would be no problem. Isn't React similar with its state?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a `BehaviorSubject` to track observable state:

```
var widgetState = new Rx.BehaviorSubject({ wasClicked: false, title: 'foo' });

// change state, probably in response to UI events
// Note we always set the full state, not just the "delta"
widgetState.onNext({ wasClicked: true, title: 'foo2' });

// example listening to title input field and updating state
// assumes rxjs-jquery
$("#title").onAsObservable("change").subscribe (function (ev) {
    var oldState = widgetState.value;
    var newTitle = $("#title").val();
    // do not mutate the oldState object, instead clone it and change the title
    var newState = $.extend({}, oldState, { title: newTitle });

    // send the update
    widgetState.onNext(newState);
});

// listen to new state values, probably to update your HTML?
widgetState.subscribe(function (newState) { ... });

// listen only when wasClicked is true
widgetState
    .filter(function (s) { return s.wasClicked; })
    .subscribe(function (s) { ... });
```

Comment: This looks great. I could apply this to my use case. Some follow up questions: Why shouldn't I mutate the old state like `state.value. wasClicked = true; state.onNext(state.value);`? What are the downsides? Wouldn't it result in garbage collection problems, if I clone the old state  on every change? And one meta question: Do you know a good guide to learn RxJS (https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/tree/master/doc/designguidelines)? Something "guided", not an API documentation. (The RxJS documentation is _really_ good to look something up, but it can be a little bit hard to get started.)

Comment: The only other guide I know is https://gist.github.com/staltz/868e7e9bc2a7b8c1f754.

Comment: Treating data as immutable is a functional programming concept that is normally used to reduce the amount of thread synchronization you must perform.  This concept of immutability is also very useful when sending data through observable streams because you don't always know what a downstream observer is doing with the data it sees.  If the downstream observer keeps a reference to the data, and you change that data at the source, then the observer will often get confused.

Comment: A simple: the `distinctUntilChanged` operator keeps a reference to the previous value and compares it to the new value.  If you mutate the value and then "send it again", you will trick the `distinctUntilChanged` operator into thinking the value has not changed.  Learning to treat data within immutable streams as immutable will save you alot of trouble debugging weird problems and also makes it much easier to write observable operations since you can hang on to references and *know* the objects they refer to won't change mysteriously.

Comment: This is a good [interactive tutorial](http://reactive-extensions.github.io/learnrx/).  And this is a [good read](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=205219) for understanding the grammar and philosophy of Rx.

Comment: p.s. excessive GC activity is a valid concern when using immutable objects.  But it is extremely unlikely to be an issue in "normal" code, especially code that is binding data to HTML DOM elements.  The user just does not change the value nearly fast enough for GC slowdowns to ever be noticeable.  Now, if you were coding the render loop of a WebGL animation then you might need to concern yourself with minimizing object allocations.  But usually it just is not a measurable concern.

Comment: Thank you for the in-depth answers. One more question: If I shouldn't pass a "delta" to `onNext` what would be the best way to get notified on certain property changes?  Should I create a `BehaviorSubject` for every property (most RxJS examples seem to "track" a single value) or should I `filter` every property from a single `BehaviorSubject` and look for changes?

Comment: the number of observable properties you use is usually dictated by your domain model or desired transaction boundaries.  If you want to "break apart" a compound object and observe individual properties, you can use `distinctUntilChanged` with a custom comparer that only compares the property you want to observe changing.  Or use `map` to extract the single property, followed by `distinctUntilChanged`.  Depends on the scenario.  Post it as a new question if you want an example